# Laravel belongsTo - Specifying fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, relational-database

I am working on a belongsTo relationship but needs to know how to specify which fields to related.

I have a reports and a cars table.

The car table has the ID field as the UI. When a report is made on a car, I wish that car to be removed from a list so I will use a scope.

In my reports table, I am storing the cars ID as 'vehicle_id'.

I have a belongsTo:

```
public function deliveryProfitReports()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('DeliveryProfitReport', 'vehicle_id');
}
```

Which is returning an errors because its looking for a vehicle_id field in the cars table.

How can I change this function so it specifys the car ID is the vehicle_id.

EDIT: Fixed the error:

```
public function deliveryProfitReports()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('DeliveryProfitReport', 'id', 'vehicle_id');
}
```

But this scope:

```
public function scopeNoDeliveryReports($query) {
    return $query->doesntHave('deliveryProfitReports');
}

$cars = Car::orderBy('RegistrationNumber')
    ->noDeliveryReports()
    ->get();
```

Doesn't work as expected and remove the rows...

What next?

Comment: I believe you need `hasOne` instead of `belongsTo`

Comment: Correct @lukasgeiter I also made the mistake of having a tinyint field so the id was actually always wrong. After changing this and your suggestion everything is okay.

Comment: Great! I just added a little answer you can accept to mark this question as solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the foreign key is in the *other table* you actually want to use `hasOne`:

```
return $this->hasOne('DeliveryProfitReport', 'vehicle_id');
```

*(Besides that OP also had a DB problem because of a wrong data type)*